# How do I separate elements by their type with an each method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

I created two scaffolds: announce_sections and announcements. The announce_sections are the types of announcements there are (i.e. games, tryouts, etc) and when I create an announcement I specify what type of announce_sections it is. I'm trying to display it so that each announce_section is viewed, with each announcement and its information under the announce_section. This is what I came up with:

```
  <% @announce_sections.each do |announce_section| %>
    <%= announce_section.name %>
    <% @announcements.each do |announcement| %>
      <%= announcement.announcement_title %>
      <%= announcement.information %>
      <%= announcement.additional_information %>
      <%= announcement.type %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

However, this code only displays the announce_sections with the **all** announcements under it. The announcements don't get separated into their respective announce_sections. How do I change it so that it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @announce_sections.each do |announce_section| %>
  <%= announce_section.name %>
  <% @announcements.where(type: announce_section).each do |announcement| %>
      <%= announcement.announcement_title %>
      <%= announcement.information %>
      <%= announcement.additional_information %>
      <%= announcement.type %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Use the name of the field you are using to assign the announcement type instead of 'type'

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, but one simple one is to build a hash where the key is the type of `announcement_section` and the value is an array (or Set) of the announcement. One way to build that hash is to use the `Hash.new {|hash, key| ... }` form of the constructor.

```
@hash = Hash.new {|hash, section| hash[section] = Array.new }
@announcements.each do |a|
  # for each announcment append it to the array under the hash
  @hash[a.section] << a
end
```

And then, in the view

```
<% @hash.keys.each do |section| %>
  <%= section %>
  <% @hash[section].each do |announcement| %>
    <%= announcement.announcement_title %>
    <%= announcement.information %>
    <%= announcement.additional_information %>
    <%= announcement.type %>         
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```